# Why does this image keep moving down (objective-c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm using **UIKit** to create a simple game. In my game, I want the ball to completely stop moving if its upMovement is less than -4.

So it appears to freeze in mid air.

What I have is the following:

```
    if (upMovement < -4) {

    upMovement = 0;
    ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x, ball.center.y);

    ball.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"fallingball.png"], nil];
    [ball setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    ball.animationDuration = 1;
    [ball startAnimating];
}
```

I thought by adding `upMovement = 0;` and `ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x, ball.center.y)` it would freeze the ball as soon as the `upMovement < -4` ? but instead it, just makes it move really slow.

Any reasons as to why?

Comment: Help me out - what do you think "ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x, ball.center.y);" should be doing?

Comment: Add at first of if statement `[myView.layer removeAllAnimations];`

Comment: @AdamEberbach i assumed it would just create a point wherever the ball was, and because the up movement was 0, i thought it would be that stationary point, is there another way to go about this ?

Comment: @iPatel the animations are only to change the image, they don't affect the movement

Comment: Liam - seems like there's more research required here. Is this if() block handling the top of the parabola in your ball's flight animation? Do you have other if()s for rising and falling? It's one way to do it but maybe not the best. If you want the movement to look natural, look into SpriteKit for a dedicated library designed to make this easy. But your setting of the ball.center property there is a nop, you are setting it to the value it already has.

Comment: You might like to look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners to see an example of SpriteKit code.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I've read abit about SpriteKit but it would just be such a colossal step backwards because this is the last step before completing this game for me, and for what this game is, it would be a waste of time. I took the CGPointMake out but it still does it. I'm not sure where to go from here. Hmm. That being said, thanks for all the help @AdamEberbach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ball view is animating because of an UIView animation block or similar, then

```
[ball.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

should remove that animation and freeze it in place.

If you're animating it in place by repeatedly changing its frame then you would just have to stop doing that.